# Cannot launch Pydev5.0.0 in Eclipse3.8

Tags: python, eclipse

I installed Eclipse3.8 in Ubuntu 16.04LTS, and my Java version is JDK8. I installed Pydev5.0.0 and I could see "PyDev for Eclipse" in "Installation Details". However, I could find pydev after restart, even in Windows->perference or perspective.
I searched some previous related articles, but nothing works for me.